# I want to get a 'INT' value from a DB::Select get()

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a simple login and redirect each user to their private page, so each user will have their own page. Like www.example.com/user1.

This is for my new Application that I'm developing in this job.

```
public function login(request $req){
    $username = $req->input('username');
    $password = $req->input('password');
    $type = 1;
    $checklogin = DB::table('users')->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password])->get();
    $checktype = DB::table('users')->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password,'type'=>$type])->get();        
    $url2 = DB::table('users')->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password])->get('id');
    if(count($checklogin) >0){
        if (count($checktype) ==1) {
            header("Location: /admin/$url2", true, 301);
            exit();
        }else{
            if ($url2 == 4) {              
                echo "$url2";
            }
        }
    }else{
        return view('loginfailed');
    }
}
}
```

The url that is redirecting is: "http://localhost:8000/admin/[%7B%22id%22:2%7D]"

Comment: Check the type of `$checktype`

Comment: In the database users I have on column called type so if it is 1 is an admin and if it is 2 is a normal user

Comment: **`[{"id":2}]`**  is url encoded to `[%7B%22id%22:2%7D]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
public function login(request $req){
    $username = $req->input('username');
    $password = $req->input('password');
    $checklogin = DB::table('users')->select('type')->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password])->get()->first();

    if(count($checklogin){
        if ($checklogin->type ==1) {
            header("Location: /admin/$url2", true, 301);
            exit();
        }elseif ($checklogin->type == 4) {              
                //do something else
        }
    }else{
        return view('loginfailed');
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch id as,

```
// fetching 1 record and then id of it
$url2 = DB::table('users')->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password])->first()->id;
```